# Anything start with http:// is validated by FILTER_VALIDATE_URL?

Tags: php, validation, uri

I tested with strings and int that I can imagine, as long as it start with http://, it will be a valid url using FILTER_VALIDATE_URL. So, why we need FILTER_VALIDATE_URL? Why not just add http:// on an input whenever we want to make it valid?

```
var_dump(filter_var ('http://example',FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ));
```

Comment: show us what you tested and how.

Comment: try http://20 , http://example,  they are valid

Comment: rhe code you used to do the testing is ?

Comment: var_dump , it returns the url

Comment: why so resistant just to post your code? well i give up.

Comment: var_dump(filter_var ('http://example',FILTER_VALIDATE_URL )); the http is lost when posted in the comment box

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well technically, any URI that starts with a scheme (like `http://`) and contains valid URI characters after that **is valid** as per the official URI specification in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.1):

> Each URI begins with a scheme name, as defined in Section 3.1, that refers to a specification for assigning identifiers within that scheme.  As such, the URI syntax is a federated and extensible naming system wherein each scheme's specification may further restrict the syntax and semantics of identifiers using that scheme.

So there's nothing strange about the return you're getting -- that's what's supposed to happen. As to why you should use the `filter_var` with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` flag ... it's way more semantically appropriate than doing something like the following for every possible URL scheme, wouldn't you agree?

```
if (strpos($url, 'http://') === 0
    || strpos($url, 'ftp://') === 0
    || strpos($url, 'telnet://') === 0
) {
    // it's a valid URL!
}
```

Comment: I see. I expected the filter to validate if a url include a valid domain or not. So, my assumption is wrong.

Comment: @Jenny If that's what you're looking for, after doing the filter call, simply pass the returned value to [`parse_url`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and you can get a nice associative array listing the URI's component parts.